# Need help Confluent Kafka .net Core client trying to produce/consume message to and from Kafka cluster(Linux server) using SASL Kerberos authenticatio

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, kerberos, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to work on the Kafka connectivity issue.
Basically I am trying be produce/consume from .net core confluent kafka to kafka cluster( linux server)
and I am facing various issues.
I am using Confluent.Kafka(.net) 1.7.0 version to connect to  Kafka cluster verion:2.7.2
My confluent kafka .net is being used in the docker container.

I am trying to run my .net core c# api in a docker container and I am getting following runtime errors:

```
No provider for SASL mechanism GSSAPI: recompile librdkafka with libsasl2 or openssl support. Current build options: PLAIN SASL_SCRAM OAUTHBEARER -    
at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.Create(RdKafkaType type, IntPtr config, IClient owner)
at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2..ctor(ProducerBuilder`2 builder)
at Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder`2.Build()
```

Anyone has some experience with this kind of problem.

Update:
I did and I ended up following [link][Confluent Kafka Dotnet Kerberos Support Dockerfile (No provider for SASL mechanism GSSAPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009427/confluent-kafka-dotnet-kerberos-support-dockerfile-no-provider-for-sasl-mechani) article.
Made changes to dockerfile to complete the steps.  After installing on container I am getting following msg:

> When users attempt to use Kerberos and specify a principal or user name without specifying what administrative Kerberos realm that principal belongs to, the system appends the default realm.  The default realm may also be used as the realm of a Kerberos service running on the local machine.  Often, the default realm is the uppercase version of the local DNS domain.

Comment: Have you searched elsewhere for this `recompile librdkafka with libsasl2 or openssl support`? There should be documentation available in the librdkafka (or dotnet-kafka) repos for how to do that

Comment: @OneCricketeer   I did try more stuff with no luck. I have added a update to my original comment

Comment: Your new error message sounds like you didn't specify a realm in your sasl config